# React Native Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.userAgent.indexOf')

Tags: react-native

We're getting this problem when creating an application with react-native init.

The error is "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.userAgent.indexOf')"  When we do remote debugging in the browser, this doesn't happen. It runs fine in that situation.

Also when we build it out as a standalone APK, the app immediately crashed.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution to this problem. I am facing the exact same scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashes on start when remote debugging is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798615/app-crashes-on-start-when-remote-debugging-is-disabled)

Comment: Hehe. This question was asked months before i did. I thought maybe they figured it out.