# App crashes on start when remote debugging is disabled

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to install my react-native app on my phone (iPhone). It installs alright but then crashes on start with this error message -

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.userAgent.indexOf')

<unknown>
     :12:71
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:213:12
<unknown>
    getScrollPosition.js:12:31
```

If i then enable remote js debugging, it reloads and everything works fine. I disable remote debugging, the app goes back to crashing. Any idea what might be happening here?

Update - The culprit code is in fbjs package - https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs/src/core/dom/getDocumentScrollElement.js

They check if `navigator` is defined or not and then try to access the second level property on it - `navigator.userAgent.indexOf`.

I can either fake `navigator.userAgent` somehow or send a PR to fbjs.

Comment: Could you post `getScrollPosition.js:12:31` and the required module code?

Comment: That's not my code. I think it's one of the third party libraries. Probably from draftjs. I will check and get back.

Comment: it's coming from fbjs - https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs/src/core/dom/getDocumentScrollElement.js 

:)

Comment: draftjs relies on some browser API such as '[navigator.userAgent](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/c69904a511b900266935168223063dd8772dfc40/packages/fbjs/src/core/dom/getDocumentScrollElement.js#L15)'. Michael Cheng's answer explains why it doesn't work without debugger attached.

Comment: It's only checking for navigator undefined or not but then goes ahead and access the second level property (navigator.userAgent.indexOf). It finds the userAgent property attached to navigator when the debugger is attached but does not find it other wise

Comment: @MukeshSoni Check the edit to my answer showing exactly what the React Native JavaScript core does. It should be clear why `navigator.userAgent.indexOf` is throwing the `undefined` error. If it's still unclear, post a comment and I can break it down even further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator) is a global Web API available in browsers. This is not available in React Native as it's not a web browser. All of the Web APIs are not part of the global environment. This is why `navigator.userAgent.indexOf` is throwing the `undefined` error.

Now the reason why your program runs fine when debugging JS remotely is because React Native will switch to using the JavaScript engine provided by Chrome (or whatever you are debugging through) instead of the core one when you remote debug. So when debugging, you will have access to the global Web API that browsers normally have.

This is a very tricky gotcha that will often trip people up as most people develop with debugging turned on all the time. Rule of thumb: React Native is not a browser. Don't use any of the globals that you would normally use when doing web development and you'll avoid most of these types of gotcha errors.

If you would like to see how these globals are polyfilled (often with empty objects) in React Native's JavaScript engine, you'll want to look at [initializeCore.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js). Here you can see that React Native will polyfill `navigator` like this:

```
// Set up Geolocation
let navigator = global.navigator;
if (navigator === undefined) {
  global.navigator = navigator = {};
}

// see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10881
polyfillObjectProperty(navigator, 'product', () => 'ReactNative');
polyfillObjectProperty(navigator, 'geolocation', () => require('Geolocation'));
```

**Edit:** To answer the follow-up and give a workaround.

You can shim it, but you need to do it before importing any of your other files in `index.js` (the root of your application). This is [how it's done in `node-libs-react-native`](https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native#globals) with their [globals.js](https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native/blob/master/globals.js) file where they too set a default user agent string. Adapting that, you can achieve the same result by doing the following:

1. Create file to hold your shims, `globals.js`:

   ```
   global.navigator.userAgent = 'React Native';
   ```
2. Import/Require it prior to importing any of your other files in `index.js`:

   ```
   import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
   import globals from "./globals";
   import App from "./App";

   AppRegistry.registerComponent("RNSandbox", () => App);
   ```

If for some reason you want the `userAgent` to be different or be dependent on whether you are debugging or not, you can add your own logic to the `globals.js`.

Comment: Yeah i got that. This is the culprit file - https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs/src/core/dom/getDocumentScrollElement.js

I tried putting a dummy userAgent by adding global.navigator.userAgent = 'dummyAgent' in index.js file, but that did not work. Seemed too late in the chaing. Where should i put my polyfill code?

Comment: Any suggestions Michael?

Comment: @MukeshSoni Was working on something. I edited in a method for shimming in a dummy value for `userAgent`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I can't understand why it didn't work when i put the same line (global.navigator.userAgent = 'React Native') directly as the first statement in index.js?

Comment: @MukeshSoni Very good question, but it's really out of scope for this question. I think I'll actually post a question about this on my own since I don't have time to dive into it. My guess is that it has something to do with imports, scope, and babel. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hysan/a47c17f0b8ac04be86abf17b2b6f496d) and take a look at the comment in the App.js file to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the gist!